# How to set up MPI_COMM_SPAWN to behave like mpirun?

Tags: c++, c, mpi, openmpi

I use MPI (openMPI 3.0.1) in C for my work and i want to know how to set up mpi_comm_spawn to behave as if I run my executable with mpirun ?

I use this hostfile :

```
# This is a single processor node: 

# This is a height-processor node. Oversubscribing
# to it is prevented by setting max-slots=4:

# host  | rank | nb procs | max nb procs
  node7   0,2    slots=2    max-slots=4

# This is a height-processor node. Oversubscribing
# to it is prevented by setting max-slots=8:

# host  | rank        | nb procs | max nb procs
  node8   1,3,4,5,6,7   slots=6    max-slots=8
```

so when I launch `hostname` with

```
mpirun -hostfile /path/to/mpi_hostfile hostname
```

I gave

```
node7
node7
node8
node8
node8
node8
node8
node8
```

but when I spawn new processes with (warning this is pseudo code)

```
maxprocs = to_unsigned(arg)
info_key = "add-hostfile"
info_value = "/path/to/mpi_hostfile"

mpi_comm_spawn(....)
```

and this is the code I use

```
mpi->comm_spawn->set_attr_command(argv[0]);
mpi->comm_spawn->set_attr_argv(argv + 1);
mpi->comm_spawn->set_attr_maxprocs(universe_size - 1);

if (mc_options.hostfile == nullptr)
  mpi->comm_spawn->set_attr_info(spot::mpi::info_null);
else
  {
     // OpenMPI specific
     const char* hostfile = "add-hostfile";

     mpi->info_create->set_attr_info(&info);
     mpi->info_create->do_info_create();

     mpi->info_set->set_attr_info(info);
     mpi->info_set->set_attr_key(hostfile);
     mpi->info_set->set_attr_value(mc_options.hostfile);
     mpi->info_set->do_info_set();

     mpi->comm_spawn->set_attr_info(info);
   }

 mpi->comm_spawn->set_attr_root(master);
 mpi->comm_spawn->set_attr_comm(spot::mpi::comm_self);
 mpi->comm_spawn->set_attr_intercomm(&children);
 mpi->comm_spawn->
 set_attr_array_of_errcodes(spot::mpi::errcodes_ignore);
 mpi->comm_spawn->do_comm_spawn();
```

I Have all my processes on node7 and I can't launch more than 2 processes (like I specifying in mpi_hostfile for node7)

```
Process #0: on HOST node7
Process #1: on HOST node7
```

if I try to launch more

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
There are not enough slots available in the system to satisfy the 3 slots
that were requested by the application:
/* my executable*/

Either request fewer slots for your application, or make more slots available
for use.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[node7:2306] *** An error occurred in MPI_Comm_spawn
[node7:2306] *** reported by process [4042260481,0]
[node7:2306] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_SELF
[node7:2306] *** MPI_ERR_SPAWN: could not spawn processes
[node7:2306] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[node7:2306] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
```

and I want to have

```
node7
node7
node8
node8
node8
node8
node8
node8
```

like with mpirun
I don't understand why it's different ?

thanks.

Comment: Yes it's what I do, the program have found my hostfile

Comment: but he don't behave like I expect it

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! About your pseudo code... Could you provide us with the code part where `mpi_comm_spawn()` is called? For instance, the fact that `info_key = "add-hostfile" info_value = "/path/to/mpi_hostfile"` suggests that `MPI_Info_set()` is called before `mpi_comm_spawn()`. Is it the case? Could you show us you it is done?

Comment: thanks for your comment, yes i do it.

Comment: I have add an edit with the full code

Comment: I assume that the string `mc_options.hostfile` actually contains a path to the expected hostfile. Could you try to open/close this file within the MPI program to check that it visible and readable by the process? Could you also check that [`MPI_Info_set()`](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v2.0/man3/MPI_Info_set.3.php) is successful by testing the errorcode? Indeed,it might fail if a `value` ( here the path to the hostfile)  is too long. As an alternative, the feature `MPI_UNIVERSE_SIZE` could help finding the number of available slots for spawning: simply substract the size of MPI_COMM_WORLD.